# Tailwind CSS group-hover with transition

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am using the following component:
https://tailwindcomponents.com/component/dropdown-shopping-cart
and I want the menu to be opened for 3 seconds after hovering.
What I understand is that the thing that is responsible for the dropdown to be shown after hover is the
`<div class="relative group">` and the
`group-hover:block`. To get the effect I want I thought about maybe adding a transition with certain duration but I can't get this to work.

Comment: Could you please try to state want you need more precisely. What is the menu (is it the box containing products + checkout button, ie everything after row 17 is component code?) What should be hovered (only the shopping cart image? the "menu" also?) Should the "menu" appear directly when the shopping cart image is hovered and disappear after 3 seconds?

Comment: The dropdown menu should be appear instant after hovering and stay opened for 3 seconds. the "menu" is the whole div from the first product to the checkout. @kenshuri